# Article visibility using data categories

Tags: knowledge, articles, lightning-knowledge, data-category

I am trying to hide certain articles for certain users based on the article's data category.

I've set the data category visibility to None on the user profile, user role, permission sets and even on the default data category visibility, but somehow the user can still see the article I am trying to hide.

The weird thing is that the user can find the article, but cannot see it's content. Here's a screenshot:

[image: screen]

As you can see, the user is able to find and access the article, but cannot see any of the data in it, including the article's associated data category.

Is this the normal behaviour, or there's something I am missing?

Thanks